# Does Android API 18 supports jdk1.7.0_80?

Tags: java, android, java-7, java-6

I use jdk1.7.0_80 for my project but there is a `.jar` file which apparently compiled with jdk1.6. I'm getting some exception related to that library and tells some files are not defined but I didn't modify anything related to that since six months ago. I want to know the conflict between used JDKs break something?

Answer (score 0):

if you open old projects usually version conflicts will happen. gradle, android tools even android studio had an issue after upgrade. but in your case you say jar file compiled with 1.6 and java 7 had a problem. with java 8, my old jar file didnt created a problem in my project so you might want to delete jdk 7 and install jdk8update74, which is the latest version.

Comment: Migrating to JDK8 (latest version) doesn't make any problem? And would it help?

Comment: it was a successful upgrade on my setup.